# how to add a value from a text box to SOSL querry dynamically?

Tags: sosl

I have written an sosl querry.

```
for(List<SObject> obj:[FIND **'jose'** IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(id,name,Company,Phone,Street,City,State,PostalCode,Country,Owner.id  WHERE (Owner.id=:UserInfo.getUserId() AND Id Not IN: cartset) order by name ASC LIMIT 1000) ])
```

Instead of 'jose', I am trying to pass a value that i fetched from a text box in VF page.

how can i attain it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String var = 'jose';
String searchquery = 'FIND\'' + var + '\'IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(...)'; 
List<List<SObject>>searchList = search.query(searchquery);
```

Comment: i am getting this error :System.QueryException: unexpected token: FINDnull

Comment: Did you keep the space after `FIND` and before `IN` ? And it seems that your var `jose` is null.

Comment: i have used spaces and assigned value for jose.
the below error is reported
"System.QueryException: unexpected token: FIND "

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: `[FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ...]` avoids potential errors from special characters, etc.